# Transposing one column from first to final cell to a different location

Tags: excel, vba

What I wish to end up with

[image]

```
Sub Traping()

Dim r As Range, N As Long, t As Variant
N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set r = Cells(N, 1).EntireColumn

r.Copy
'Cells(N + 1, 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

t = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(r)
Range("N1", Cells(N + 1, 1)).Value = t


'r.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: `Set r =Range("A1",Cells(N,"A"))` and `Range("N1").Resize(1,r.rows.count).Value = Application.Transpose(r.value)`

Comment: it worked! Thank you so much!!!